# httpd access log, ip logged is reversed proxy how to find actual proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, reverse-proxy

Check access log and found out that the IP that was logged from users came from the reversed proxy server.

The setup is like this

```
www.abc.com -> reversed proxy to my server 123.123.123.123
```

Is there anyway to configure the http access log to tracked actual incoming IP behind reversed proxy server?

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for the `X-Forwarded-For` header. Any proxy worth its salt will add this header to HTTP requests it is forwarding.

If your entire site is behind this proxy, then you need to find the relevant `LogFormat` for it, which will typically look like this:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

and add the header to it (or swap out the `%h` which is only ever going to be your reverse proxy) like this:

```
LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

If you don't want to redefine the `combined` log format then create your own:

```
LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined_proxy
CustomLog /path/to/logfile.log combined_proxy
```

`%{<header>}i` is a way to get any other request header into your log files.

*Note:* That header will not always necessarily be a single IP address. If the request has come through more than one proxy, then you'll get a comma separated list of the form: `client, proxy1, proxy2`; you may need to update your scripts or log scrapers to accommodate this.

Comment: Note, depending on how you  reverse proxy is configured, you may have to use X-Real-IP instead (used in a lot of nginx reverse proxy howtos)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is.

For the current version of Apache: [mod_rpaf](http://stderr.net/apache/rpaf/)
For anything later than the 2.3 branch: [mod_remoteip](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/mod/mod_remoteip.html)

Both of these will replace the `REMOTE_ADDR` variable in the running Apache process with the last IP from the incoming `X-Forwarded-For` header from any trusted reverse proxy.  This IP address will also be logged in your standard Apache logs without having to change them at all.

This variable will also be available to your PHP code as `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` which is where you would normally expect the remote IP address to be.

The only configuration that is required for these modules it to supply them with a list of trusted reverse proxies.

On a security note, these headers can be added, removed, faked and possibly mangled.  There is no guarantee that any IP address you get from this header is the *true* IP address of the visitor.  The last one in the list (which is the one added by your trusted reverse proxy) is the only one you can be certain of.