# phpmyadmin scan from server IP address

Tags: apache-2.2

I have number of such records in my Apache log:

```
[Tue Dec 20 01:31:45 2011] [error] [client 192.0.79.172] File does not exist: /var/www/user/data/www/example.com/phpMyAdmin-2.5.4
```

Where 192.0.79.172 is my server external IP address configured on eth0. Clearly, someone is scanning server on subject of phpmyadmin vulnerabilities. But why all such logs entries show my own server IP address not the attacker? I would like to block such scans. I feel I'm missing something. I use CentOS 5.7 if it matters.

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

```
grep  proxy /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf 

LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
# enable the proxy server:
#<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
#   CacheRoot "/var/cache/mod_proxy"
# End of proxy directives.
```

I should have mentioned that I have nginx before Apache, but that does not change anything. The same situation had occurred before we deployed nginx as a reverse-proxy.

Comment: It seems that the attacks are occuring from your own server, are their clients on your server ?

Comment: does `grep -d proxy /path/to/httpd.conf` return anything?

Comment: Yes, we have one user and one site. Should I do malware scan?

Comment: I'd go what Chris suggests, just bear in mind it might be your user performing a PMA scan with a script, it would not turn up as malware. It might be your system is compromised in one way or another.

Comment: Definitely have mod_proxy loaded, and it looks like it might be enabled too though that specific directive isn't in the above output. Is there a reason you've got Apache acting as a proxy? It's very easy to create a mod_proxy configuration where it's open for anyone to use as an open proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With default setup you will always have your server IP in Apache logs, because Nginx is a client here. You can try adding some options to Nginx to pass real IP:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

Or you can enable and examine Nginx logs.

Comment: Forgive me my stupidity, yes I have checked nginx access log and the attacker IP is clearly seen.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need [mod_rpaf](http://stderr.net/apache/rpaf/).  I answered a question on this a [few minutes ago](https://serverfault.com/questions/349573/httpd-access-log-ip-logged-is-reversed-proxy-how-to-find-actual-proxy/350661#350661).

The [phpMyAdmin scans are fairly normal](http://blog.spiderlabs.com/2012/01/honeypot-alert-extensive-setupphp-scanning-detected.html).  If you have phpMyAdmin installed you should restrict access to it using either HTTP Basic Auth or an IP address restriction and if you don't have it installed these will just be harmless 404s.

You can also find the original IP address in your nginx logs.